# how to reset selection of combobox in kendo ui for angular

Tags: combobox, angular5, reset, kendo-ui-angular2

When I invoke reset method of ComboBox, The text will be modified with null value, but the selection doesn't change. Can anyone give some suggestion to solve the problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function reset doesn't work if you use in (selectionChange) function.
But When you use the Method in other code section, the method works fine.
Amazing!

```
selectionChange(val: any): void {
  this.combo.reset(); // doesn't work
}
resetComboBox(): void {
  this.combo.reset(); // work fine
}
```